# ¿Cómo hago una consulta para el calculo de horas trabajadas con Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> Necesito realizar una consulta que me de como resultado en un solo registro el registro estado(0)Entrada y el de estado(1)salida de un empleado, para posteriormente yo realizar el calculo del tiempo realizado.
>   Si el marcajes es una Entrada -> Estado = 0, si el marcaje es una Salida -> Estado = 1

Tengo esta estructura..

### tabla Marcajes.

```
id_marcajes - int
id_usuario - int
fecha - date
hora - time
segundos - int
estado - tinyint
```

---

```
id - 1
id_usuario - 1
fecha - 2019-10-17
hora - 07:00:00
segundos  - 25200
estado - 0
```

---

```
id - 2
id_usuario - 1
fecha - 2019-10-17
hora - 13:00:00
segundos - 46800
estado - 1
```

---

Lo que quiere es que me empareje en un mismo registro los estados... es decir...

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
id      id_usuario      fecha       horaE       horaS      estadoE     estadoS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          1         2019-10-17     07:00:00   13:00:00       0           1
2          1         2019-10-17     15:00:00   20:00:00       0           1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tengo esta pero no me funciona porque me salen los registros repetidos...

```
select  a.id_usuario, a.fecha, a.hora as horaE, a.estado as EstadoE, 
        a.segundos AS segundosI, m.segundos as segundosF, m.segundos- 
        a.segundos as diferencia, m.id_usuario, m.fecha, m.hora as horaS, 
        m.estado as EstadoS, e.id_empleado, e.nombre as nombreEmpleado 
from marcajes as a 
inner join marcajes as m on a.id_usuario = m.id_usuario 
        and a.estado <> m.estado and a.fecha = m.fecha 
        and (a.fecha >= '2019-10-01' and a.fecha<= '2019-10-17') 
        and a.segundos < m.segundos and a.estado < m.estado 
 inner join empleado as e on e.id_empleado = a.id_usuario 
 order by a.id_usuario asc, a.fecha asc, a.hora asc
```

Comment: Para evitar registros repetidos basta con poner la palabra reservada DISTINCT después del SELECT, tu query empezaría así: select distinct a.id_usuario, ...

Comment: yo creo que lo mejor para tu caso es tener dos tablas: marcajesIn y marcajesOut, donde registras las entradas y salidas respectivamente, de esta manera es mas sencilla la consulta y además conviene tenerlo en tablas separadas para mejor eficiencia de tu programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar estás tratando de Analizar si un empleado entró a una hora y también saber a que hora salió (ese mismo día) por lo cual necesitas una tabla que se arma en función a las entradas y las salidas

Entonces tienes que hacer 2 consultas 1 de entradas y otras de salidas

```
Select * from marcajes where estado = 0 -  SC1
Select * from marcajes where estado = 1 - SC2
```

Después hacer un left_join join entre ellas considerando la llave id_empleado + fecha

```
Select SC1.id_empleado, SC1.fecha, SC1.Hora, SC2.Hora, SC1.Estado, SC2.Estado  
from (Select * from marcajes where estado = 0) SC1 left join (Select * from marcajes where estado = 1) SC2
on SC1.id_empleado||SC1.fecha = SC2.id_empleado||SC2.fecha
```

En caso un empleado pueda entrar y salir más de una vez durante el día podrías hacer esto:

```
Select SC1.id_empleado, SC1.fecha, SC1.Hora, min(SC2.Hora - SC1.Hora), 
from (Select * from marcajes where estado = 0) SC1 left join (Select * from marcajes where estado = 1) SC2
on SC1.id_empleado||SC1.fecha = SC2.id_empleado||SC2.fecha
GROUP BY SC1.id_empleado, SC1.fecha, SC1.Hora
```

Hay maneras para colocar SC2.Hora, haciendo otra consulta adicional que tenga como subconsulta la que acabo de hacer sería una, lamentablemente se pierde eficiencia debido a que se está haciendo 2 subconsultas.

Saludos

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por tu aporte.. Tengo un problema con esta consulta, me repiten los datos.. y ademas.. por ejemplo me sale en un registro la entrada : 07:00:00 y la Salida a las 20:00:00 la cual cosa es verdad, pero ..la salida de las 20:00:00 viene de la entrada de las 15:00:00 .. no.. de las 07:00:00.. al unir los estado=0 con estado 0 1... es lo que me pasa... No se si me he explicado bien...

Comment: Si las horas de entrada marcan la pauta, podrías hacer una consulta con GROUP BY, elaboro en la propuesta original

Comment: Gracias Albert por el aporte .. lo pruebo.. a ver. que tal..

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que necesitas es agrupar y contar con una condición, algo así:

```
SELECT
  a.id_usuario,
  a.fecha,
  group_concat(IF(a.estado = 0, a.hora, '')) as horaE,
  group_concat(IF(a.estado = 1, a.hora, '')) as horas,
  SUM(IF(a.estado = 0, 1, 0)) as EstadoE,
  SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, 1, 0)) as EstadoS,
  e.nombre as nombreEmpleado,
  SUM(IF(a.estado = 0, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)) as diferencia
FROM
  marcajes as a
  INNER JOIN empleado as e ON e.id_empleado = a.id_usuario
WHERE
  (
    a.fecha >= '2019-10-01'
    and a.fecha <= '2019-10-17'
  )
GROUP BY
  e.id_empleado,
  a.fecha
ORDER BY
  a.id_usuario asc,
  a.fecha asc,
  a.hora asc
```

Pruebalo y me comentas. 
Espero sea de ayuda, Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte..es un gran consulta... yo no estoy aún .. a ese nivel .. , La funcion group_concat , entiendo que utilizas el campo separador para poner la hora de cada registro, me sale en el siguiente formato: ,15:00:00,,07:00:00,. Se pueden quitar las , comas , y poner otro tipo de campo separador, por ejemplo '/'? , y que pueda salir este formato-> 07:00:00/13:00:00/15:00:00/20:00:00 ? Gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo en responder

Comment: Si claro, es posible cambiar tu separador usando el atributo separator de la siguiente manera: GROUP_CONCAT(IF(a.estado = 0, a.hora, '') SEPARATOR '/'). Espero te sea util. Saludos.

Comment: Buenos dias. Como puedo.. realizar un if dentro de una sentencia referenciando un campo con AS : SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)) as diferencia, "Esta columna me retorna o un valor -negativo o un valor positivo", " Lo que quiero es realizar otra columna que me diga que si el valor que me retorna de diferencia, es negativo entonces poner un 0, si es positivo, ponerle el valor que me da el campo diferencia...y despues poder .. si se puede... sumar los valores de la columna generada..

Comment: Buenos dias @Carlos Sorribes Perat, no logro entender completamente tu pregunta, te sugiero editar tu pregunta inicial con tu duda y según ejemplo, y de ser posible califica la mejor respuesta para que los demás usuarios puedan encontrarla

Comment: Tienes razón @Jhoubert Rincon, tratare de explicarme mejor. en la sentencia anterior que me has preparado.. en "SUM(IF(a.estado = 0, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)) as diferencia", el Valor que me retorna diferencia es positivo+, ó -negativo numerico. Yo quiero que si es -negativo no me muestre ese valor, que solamente me muestre el valor positivo.. no se si es posible.., en la misma columna ó otra diferente... Saludos.

Comment: Si, es posible en la misma linea. intenta colocando un if en la columna completa así: `IF(SUM(IF(a.estado = 0, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1))>0,SUM(IF(a.estado = 0, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)),0) as diferencia`, no estoy seguro que sea la manera más optima, pero si que debe funcionar.

Comment: Mil gracias.. !!! fuenciona..Muy bien..: asi queda...IF(SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1))>0,SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)),0) as diferencia - Se podria realizar otra consulta para realizar el totalizado  SUMA ,de la columna diferencia, para poder saber las horas trabajadas de los empleado/s entre unas determinadas fechas?

Comment: Si señor, siguiendo la misma lógica podrías aplícarlo, sin el group by si quieres un total.

Comment: Buenas, he provado esta nueva sentencia, pero de da error "Invalid use of group function../ SELECT
  a.id_usuario,
  a.fecha,
  e.nombre as nombreEmpleado,
  SUM(IF(SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1))>0,SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)),0)) as diferencia
FROM
  marcajes as a
  INNER JOIN empleado as e ON e.id_empleado = a.id_usuario
WHERE
  (
    a.fecha >= '2019-06-01'
    and a.fecha <= '2019-10-17'
    and a.id_usuario = 1
   ) , Le he añadido un SUM Delante de la anterior.. pero me da error,, en teoria tendría que realizar la suma.. no?

Comment: No entendí que es lo que hiciste

Comment: Buenas .. esta sentencia la acepta: IF(SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1))>0,SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)),0) as diferencia ---- Esta no la acepta , me da error, simplemente poniendole el sum() delante..                SUM(IF(SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1))>0,SUM(IF(a.estado = 1, a.segundos, a.segundos * -1)),0)) as diferencia